# How to sort an array in php

Tags: php, sorting

i want the same value has the same index
for example

```
1 2 2 3 5
```

after sort:

```
array(
0=>1
1=>2
1=>2
3=>3
4=>5);
```

but we can not set duplicate index in the array of php.

Comment: I would say that the body of the question does not relate the title...

Comment: hehe you've got surprise everyone!

Comment: @bruce: you should write your question on the first time.

Comment: You can first remove duplicates from the array and then sort it.

Comment: but i also want the value removed

Comment: @bruce - removing the duplicate values is what `array_unique` does. Get rid of the duplicate values using `array_unique`, then sort the array with `sort`, then you're done.

Answer (score 6):

There's a [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function in php! ( I answer the topic and not the body, didn't quite follow you there, but here's how you sort in php )

**Example**

```
<?php

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");

sort($fruits);

foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```

**Duplicates**

In the above example duplicates will just have their own indexes so the array:

```
5 4 5 1 3 1 2
```

Will look like this

```
1 1 2 3 4 5 5
```

This might not be what you are looking for, what you want is another type of dataset than just a simple array, maybe you want a hashtable or just a linked list on each row.

If you are okay with it, you can remove the duplicates by using [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) 
`$newArray=array_unique($arr);`

Which would lead to having an array looking like this

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this.

```
sort($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you can't have duplicate values at the same index in an array - each index in an array has exactly one value.

As to the title of the question, to sort an array in PHP, use [`sort`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

If this doesn't answer what you're trying to ask, you might want to edit your question to make it a bit clearer (the body of the question doesn't seem particularly related to the question title).

**Post OP's edit**:

You *cannot* store multiple values at the same key, your output array (`array(0=>1, 1=>2, 1=>2, 3=>3, 4=>5);`) doesn't really make sense (the key `1` does map to the value `2`) in the sorted array. Are you trying to store counts of occurrences of numbers?

e.g. given the input:

```
1, 2, 2, 3, 5
```

get the output:

```
array(1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1, 5=>1); // there is 1 "1", there are 2 "2"s etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [array_unique](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

> `array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )`
>
> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.