# PHP sort array by filename

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The code below scans through the current folder for word documents and then spits out an array of all it finds....

```
<?php
    $a=array();
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if(preg_match("/\.doc$/", $file)) 
    $a[]=$file;
    }

    closedir($handle);

    }
    foreach($a as $i){
    echo $i;
    }
?>
```

This all works fine but the order is not what I want.  Is there a way to sort the results by filename?  I have looked at the sort function but cant figure out how to implement it in my situation.

Comment: Also, is this the most efficient way of achieving the list of filenames?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720855/how-to-sort-an-array-in-php) ...it would be to your benefit, and ours, if you get familiar with the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: [Learn](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+sort+array+by+filename) [to](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+sort+array+by+filename) [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+sort+array+by+filename)  [for](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+sort+array+by+filename) [existing](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+sort+array+by+filename), [identical](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+sort+array+by+filename) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+sort+array+by+filename).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

It operates in-place, so you don't get the sorted array as return value.

```
<?php
    $a=array();
    if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if(preg_match("/\.doc$/", $file)) 
    $a[]=$file;
    }

    closedir($handle);

    }
    sort($a);
    foreach($a as $i){
    echo $i;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ive gone with your solution, i'm sure the others would work fine but this seems the simplest :)

Comment: Simpler than just `glob('*.doc')`? `glob` is not only simpler, it's *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `glob()` which will sort them automatically for you:

```
$files = glob('*.doc');
```

See [PHP on glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for more details.

If the order is not the expected one, pass the parameter `GLOB_NOSORT` to return the files in the order they appear in the directory.

Comment: Doesn't glob's sorting depend on the OS's sorting? And don't different OS's have different methods of sorting? If not, what's up with this flag?: `GLOB_NOSORT - Return files as they appear in the directory (no sorting) `

Comment: @Madmartigan: Behavior is dependent upon libc glob which, by default, sorts alphabetically. `GLOB_NOSORT` turns this off.